# Stripe Payout testing

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payout

How can I add stripe test balance in test mode so that i can test payout.

Error message -
error handler StripeInvalidRequestError: You have insufficient funds in your Stripe account.

and the balances in stripe are as -
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `available balance` test cards that bypass pending balance and make the funds immediately available for payout testing: https://stripe.com/docs/testing#available-balance

Answer (score 1):

According to Stripe documentation at https://stripe.com/docs/connect/top-ups#testing:

> You can use the Dashboard or the API to [test adding funds to your balance](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing#testing-top-ups).